# Which package to use to create a size like blank presentation

Tags: presentations

Does someone know which latex package to use in order to make paper size like blank presentation.

Here is an example

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/video-lectures/lecture-2-conditioning-and-bayes-rule/MIT6_041F10_L02.pdf

And here is the result when showing the slides :

http://youtu.be/j9WZyLZCBzs?list=PLUl4u3cNGP60A3XMwZ5sep719_nh95qOe

Comment: Please make edit your question to make it self-contained so that it continues to be useful to others even if external content is modified or annihilated. Remember that a question on this site should concern a general issue which can be expected to be of interest to many users and not just to the person posting the question.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `beamer` or `pdfscreen` or similar?

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75646/proper-page-size-for-slides

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use four `minipage`s:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=8.5in,
    paperheight=8.5in,
    top=0.25in,
    bottom=0.25in,
    left=0.25in,
    right=0.25in,
    nomarginpar,
    footskip=15pt,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\newcommand*{\Heading}[1]{{\centering\textbf{#1}\par}}

\NewEnviron{MyBox}{%
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][0.48\textheight]{0.48\linewidth}
        \vspace*{0.5cm}%
        \BODY%
    \end{minipage}}%
    \hfill
}


\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{MyBox}
    \Heading{Lecture 2}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{Readings:} Sections 1.3--1.4.
    \end{itemize}
\end{MyBox}%
\begin{MyBox}
    \Heading{Review of Probability Models}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{Readings:} Sections 1.3--1.4.
    \end{itemize}
\end{MyBox}%
\vfill\noindent
\begin{MyBox}
    \Heading{Conditional probaility}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  Probability of A\ldots
    \end{itemize}
\end{MyBox}%
\begin{MyBox}
    \Heading{Die roll example}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  Let $B$ be the event\ldots
    \end{itemize}
\end{MyBox}%
\begin{MyBox}
    \Heading{Lecture 2}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{Readings:} Sections 1.3--1.4.
    \end{itemize}
\end{MyBox}%
\begin{MyBox}
    \Heading{Review of Probability Models}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{Readings:} Sections 1.3--1.4.
    \end{itemize}
\end{MyBox}%
\vfill\noindent
\begin{MyBox}
    \Heading{Conditional probaility}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  Probability of A\ldots
    \end{itemize}
\end{MyBox}%
\begin{MyBox}
    \Heading{Die roll example}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item  Let $B$ be the event\ldots
    \end{itemize}
\end{MyBox}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Peter, it's perfect for the "printing version". Can you tell me how I can compile your code to get the "presentation version" that's to say to show slide by slide by using a beamer in a classroom.

Comment: Swiss12000: I think @Fran's answer covers that.

Comment: Hello Fran's answer works with his code (by commenting pgfpagesuselayout). But with your code I don't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: @Swiss12000: My code does not use `beamer` for the slides.  If you are interested in a non-`beamer` solution let me know and I can look into modifying this.  Am traveling starting tomorrow so might be a while until I can get back to this though.

Comment: Hello Peter. Yes I'm very interested in your code. Now with your code I can get a printed version (4 "slide) in 1 page) and I would like to use your code to get a "presentation version" to give a lesson to students. That's to compile your code and get 1 "slide" per page...

Answer (score 2):

As commented, use the `beamer` class with the option `handout` and `pgfpges` for a 4 x 1 layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=cyan!05}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{scale=3,border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\begin{document}
\huge
\frame{\frametitle{\Huge Lecture \insertpagenumber} Bla bla bla ... }
\frame{\frametitle{\Huge Lecture \insertpagenumber} More bla bla ... }
\frame{\frametitle{\Huge Lecture \insertpagenumber} Still bla bla ... }
\frame{\frametitle{\Huge Lecture \insertpagenumber} Even more bla ... }
\end{document}
```

With a `%` before `\pgfpagesuselayout` and removing the `handout` option you can obtain the presentation version. See also about the command `\mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Slides can be done using [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer). Printing multiple logical pages on a single sheet of paper can be done using [`pdfpages`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/).